# "go get google.golang.org/grpc" failing: unrecognized import path

Tags: go, dns, raspberry-pi, raspbian, grpc

So I am trying to install my Go app's dependencies on my Raspberry 3/Raspbian system with "go get" and running into the following when trying to install gRPC for Go:

```
[pi@raspberrypi-1 camera-service] 17:32:28 % go get google.golang.org/grpc
package google.golang.org/grpc: unrecognized import path "google.golang.org/grpc" (https fetch: Get https://google.golang.org/grpc?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup google.golang.org on 192.168.1.1:53: read udp 192.168.1.64:33524->192.168.1.1:53: i/o timeout)
```

Meanwhile I am able to install other (non-google.golang.org) dependencies (for example go get github.com/asaskevich/EventBus) just fine.

To me this looks a DNS problem -- 192.168.1.1 is my router, 192.168.1.64 is my RPi. However I can resolve the address just fine:

```
[pi@raspberrypi-1 camera-service] 17:32:52 % host google.golang.org
google.golang.org is an alias for golang.org.
golang.org has address 216.58.209.145
golang.org has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:400f:804::2011
golang.org mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
golang.org mail is handled by 2 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
golang.org mail is handled by 2 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
golang.org mail is handled by 2 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

This is weird. Also I have installed the same packages on another system np.

My environment is

```
- Go 1.8.3, installed from prebuilt ARM6 binary
- export GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
- export GOPATH="/home/pi/go"
```

Comment: try `ping -a google.golang.org` that's a dns error, try to do `go get google.golang.org/grpc` in your laptop

Comment: go get google.golang.org/grpc works from my laptop like I mentioned towards the end of the post, also other services resolve google.golang.org just fine on the RPi.

Answer (score 3):

This may be because you are using the built in DNS resolver in Go, rather than delegating to the system name resolver.  When you built gRPC, did you set `CGO_ENABLED=1` ?  You can check by setting `GODEBUG=netdns=cgo` when getting gRPC:

`$ GODEBUG=netdns=cgo go get google.golang.org/grpc`

Comment: I didn't compile Go myself, I installed the pre-built ARM6 Linux package. Ah, I didn't know Go had its own DNS resolver, that explains things.

Comment: Could you try compiling go?  It's pretty easy to do and would tell you if that's the reason.